# How to rewrite url using mod rewriter in wamp 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite my url from 
localhost/fnw/detail.php?cat=2&subcat=4&title=lol%20check%20&aid=5

to

localhost/fnw/lol%20check%20.html

I searched internet from past 3 days and i couldn't find the answer. I have enabled rewrite_mod option from wamp menu and also removed # mark from LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so in httpd.conf file. I also tried to rewrite url using mod rewrite generater tool http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/ and it gave me below code to write on .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /fnw/detail.php?cat=2&subcat=4&title=$1&aid=5 [L]
```

It is not working. Can anybody help me out with this problem? Am i missing something to be changed on wamp. I am totally new on this, Looking forward for help. Thank you in advance. :)